# Two times 'that' in a relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses

I would like to ask, whether I should use two time 'that' in a relative clause. Here is my sentence:

"Especially modulating heat pumps **that** can not only be switched on and off but **that can** continuously regulate their compressor speed..."
Another option would be.
"Especially modulating heat pumps **that** can not only be switched on and off but continuously regulate their compressor speed..."

Which one sounds better for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is acceptable to use 'that' twice, in the way you have suggested here.

Considering your sentences, though, the difference in semantics may be more important to consider than the difference in style, as one construction may more accurately describe the situation.

Option 1 ("modulating heat pumps that can not only be switched on and off but that can regulate") suggests that these heat pumps can and *might* continuously regulate compressor speed.

Option 2 ("modulating heat pumps that can not only be switched on and off but continuously regulate") seems to suggest that they *do* continuously regulate compressor speed.

I would think about how to most clearly describe how your heat pumps work, and go with the most accurate construction you can make. It might be worth re-writing this sentence entirely, as the construction is complex, especially if we consider that this phrase seems to be part of a longer compound sentence.

E.g. Modulating heat pumps can be switched on and off, and can continuously regulate their compressor speed. As such, they are especially good at something.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Chris Keefe. Can I really say 'as such'. For me this does not sound that good and in this Englisch-German dictionary it is stated as colloquial language https://www.dict.cc/?s=as+such

Comment: Here is the full sentence: 'Especially modulating heat pumps that can not only be switched on and off but that can continuously regulate their compressor speed and thus their power consumption are beneficial for smart grids'

Comment: "As such" is less-frequently used than "therefore", "so", and probably many other transition words that are used in similar contexts, but it is increasing in use in contemporary publications, and is acceptable in American science writing. Use it if you like it, or use something else. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Considering your complete sentence, I would encourage you to keep your adjectives closer to the words they modify. "Especially" is out of place at the beginning of that sentence. Better: "their reduced power consumption is especially beneficial".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Chris Keefe. What adjectives are you talking about? I do not mentione anything about 'reduced consumption'. The only adjective I see is 'beneficial'.

Comment: Sorry, PeterBe - adverb. 'especially' works here if it modifies beneficial, but does not work where it is placed at the start of the sentence.